# SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY created by Django works in MySQL and SQLite, not PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql, migration

I just switched from mysql to postgres (yay!) but now on my postgres server (only) I'm getting an error that:

SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list

It's the same query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table ORDER BY '?'
```

BTW this is a query auto-generated by django.  Alternatively, any way to get django to actually render correct sql?

### Addendum

It turns out that for whatever reason, with my Postgres 8.4 production server, Django was quashing the error, while with my Postgres 9.0 dev server it was not.  I have no idea if it was related to the Postgres versions or not, but it WAS in fact **erroring in both Postgreses and NOT in MySQL**.

Comment: Hmm, I can reproduce that error by doing `SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table ORDER BY non_select_field` on pgsql 8.3. Does 9 allow this? Can we see your django query? Also, can you clarify `any way to get django to actually render correct html?`

Comment: Could you show us both queries for 8.4 and 9.0 ? I did a small test and it fails in 8.4 and 9.0, no difference at all.

Comment: I looked at the query more closely and its SELECT DISTINCT...everything under the sun... ORDER BY RANDOM().  I can see this being implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Catcall said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823888/select-distinct-order-by-created-by-django-works-in-mysql-and-sqlite-not-postgr/4826393#4826393), technically this statement is illegal and nonsensical in SQL.

However, MySQL and SQLite allow you to do a `SELECT DISTINCT id FROM test ORDER BY whatever`, while PostgreSQL does not.  It's as simple as that.

MySQL and SQLite may produce non-deterministic results using this method, I'm not sure.

However if you are ordering by `'?'`, it should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I'd expect all SQL platforms that comply with SQL standards to raise a similar error.

Think about it this way.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    c CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, c)
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES 
    (1, 'a'),
    (1, 'z'),
    (2, 'b');

SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY c;

id  c
--  -
1   a
2   b
1   z
```

Now think about what this next statement means.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM test ORDER BY c;
```

Which value of 'c' should the dbms use to position 'id' 1 in the sort order? If it chooses 'a', the order is '1,2'. If it chooses 'z', the order is '2,1'.

Comment: Yeah that makes total sense.  But shouldn't django/psycopg2 know this and render reasonable queries?  I guess there are always bugs...

Comment: @Dave: Probably because some dbms will actually execute that last query. SQLite3, for example.

Comment: Catcall, it turns out mysql actually will execute (and return 1/a // 2/b).  Turns out this never worked in postgres on either machine... but one was quashing the error for some reason.